# Rendering issue FireFox

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am creating a website and it looks differently in firefox and Safari.
This is the link to the website http://storminacupcake.com/ and you will see that there is a small issue : it looks fine in Safari, but there is a small gap between to cells in Firefox. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?
Thank you, 
Alex

Comment: I found your problem: You're using tables for layout. Try CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers recommending you to redo your site without tables are correct - **you should do this**.

However, to help you get the site you currently have working, here is the solution to your problem:

In `style.css`, change `p{margin:.0 0 .3em 0;}` to `p{margin:0 0 .1em 0}`.

Comment: I originally wrote `.2em`, but then I checked it in IE - and it still looked wrong. `.1em` makes it look acceptable in Safari, Firefox and IE, Chrome.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You just saved me from having to do it all over.
Even if I appreciate all answers, I chose this one because it solved my problem. However thank you all for your answers, and I will do that next time
Thank you a lot thirtydot !

Answer (score 1):

I did check the site on Mac with FF. With the web developer tools I see there are many uneeded or not correct html.
How did you create the site?

Try use Firebug in FF, activate it and disable styles step by step to see what it make the margin/padding problem.

Comment: I will do as you say, but could you tell me which code is unneeded ? I don't have a lot of experience but basically I used the photoshop generated website (the project I was working on was made by a graphist who created the whole design and whom I asked to export the HTML from photoshop). Afterwards, I made a CSS file in which I entered all the images as background images, then I updated the HTML with all the divs I made in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using tables for layout - if you have information that should be in a tabular format, do use them, but not for layout.

You should be using CSS for layout. There are many [tutorials](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/style/sheets/layout/advanced/) on how to do this.

Additionally, you should look for a good [reset CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset) - this will ensure that the base styles are the same across all browsers.

Comment: but then why did photoshop generate a table for the site ?

Comment: @Alexandre Cassagne - An automated tool will never do as well as a person who knows what they are doing. The code produced by some of the most used graphics software tends to be rather horrific.

Comment: I understand. It seems then that it's gonna take me a long time until I get this working :(

Comment: @Alexandre: What gave you the idea Photoshop was a web authoring tool? It's a great image editor, but it's not intended to design *entire* web pages. The only thing it knows how to do is images. That's like asking why your newsletter has rows and columns when you made it in Microsoft Excel. Embedding a chart is great; designing a newsletter in Excel is torture. If you need WYSIWYG, try Dreamweaver.